# Trouble with web services - Apache Cordova - Visual Studio 2015 Comunity

Tags: c#, android, web-services, cordova, soap

Im working on creating a mobile app based on a existing web app developed by the company that hired me and they want me to use as much as possible of the existing back-end and middleware. Im using Visual Studio Community with cordova for the hybrid app, and there are no plans on making native apps. Right now Im having severe problems with calling a SOAP web-service.

**Limitations**:

- The web app is deployed on JBOSS, and doesn't uses servlets, instead
  it calls the services with a java client
- I can only use javascript, htlm5 and CSS (due cordova, but a native API could be implemented)

**What I have tried so far**:

- Directly calling it via AJAX call, my last attempt was this:

  var productServiceUrl = "http://localhost/searchUserDataWS/SearchUserDataWS?wsdl";

  ```
  function beginSaveProduct() {
      var soapMessage =
      '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:sear="http://searchuserdataws.alist.integra.la/"> \
         <soapenv:Header/> \
         <soapenv:Body> \
            <sear:searchUserBasicData> \
               <!--Optional:--> \
               <header> \
                  <!--Optional:--> \
                  <chanel>?</chanel> \
                  <!--Optional:--> \
                  <ip>?</ip> \
                  <!--Optional:--> \
                  <user>?</user> \
               </header> \
               <!--Optional:--> \
               <email>someuser@gmail.com</email> \
            </sear:searchUserBasicData> \
         </soapenv:Body> \
      </soapenv:Envelope>' 

      $.ajax({
          url: productServiceUrl,
          type: "POST",
          dataType: "xml",
          data: soapMessage,
          complete: endSaveProduct,
          contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\""

      });
  ```

With this code Im getting a 404 error from the server, and Im 100% that the soap message is right (as I tested on SOAPui and the service answers as expected)

- I also tried with this plugin: https://github.com/doedje/jquery.soap after tweaking it a bit, I managed to get it to send the right request (again I tried it in SOAPui and got the right response) however, when I ran it in the Android Simulator I got a 500 error (internal server error). That particular error means that I contacted with the service but the XML couldn't be processed (which is weird, because the same XML on SOAPui works). I doubt that its a CORS error, since Im running everything on my localhost.
- A co-worker tried a console app with C# that got the right answer from the service. We thought about making a C# library with all the methods for calling the services however we don't know yet how to call a C# method from cordova

**My question:** What should be my next step? Creating an API that calls the services, keep trying the C# library or something different?

Comment: Next step should be figuring out how to make your code above work, because it is the best approach. I use it all the time and it should work. I cannot see any issue with your code. You're not getting the result from the Ajax (i.e. the `success` and `failure` instead of `complete`), but that is another thing. Try changing the `contentType` to just this `contentType: "text/xml", and let me know.

Comment: Just did and the 404 error persisted. Any other sugestion? Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Like I said, the Ajax call is the best approach for your case (using Cordova). I use it all the time and it should work. I cannot see any issue with your code, so let's first figure out what's going wrong. To do so, it is much easier to test it with a standard HTML page. I have such an HTML test page for every API/Webservice I use. I've created one for you already. Copy the code to an HTML page on your computer, edit the SOAP message to include the required info, and click the [Test Directly] button to test it. Once it works, you can try the [Test Via Ajax] button to submit the exact same message via Ajax. Let us know the results.

```js
function TestAjax(){
  var productServiceUrl = "http://localhost/searchUserDataWS/SearchUserDataWS?wsdl";

  var soapMessage = document.getElementById("mesage").innerHTML;

    $.ajax({
        url: productServiceUrl,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "xml",
        data: soapMessage,
        contentType: "text/xml;",
        success: function (result) { document.write(result); },
        error: function (error) { document.write(error); },
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html><header><title>Test My API</title></header>
<body>
<form method="POST" action="http://localhost/searchUserDataWS/SearchUserDataWS?wsdl">
<textarea id="mesage" style="width: 100%; height: 350px;"><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:sear="http://searchuserdataws.alist.integra.la/"> 
       <soapenv:Header></soapenv:Header> 
       <soapenv:Body> 
          <sear:searchUserBasicData> 
             <!--Optional:--> 
             <header> 
                <!--Optional:--> 
                <chanel>?</chanel> 
                <!--Optional:--> 
                <ip>?</ip> 
                <!--Optional:--> 
                <user>?</user> 
             </header> 
             <!--Optional:--> 
             <email>someuser@gmail.com</email> 
          </sear:searchUserBasicData> 
       </soapenv:Body> 
    </soapenv:Envelope></textarea>
<br/><br/>
<input type="submit" value="Test Directly" />
<input type="button" value="Test Via Ajax" onclick="TestAjax();" />
</form>
</html>
</body>
```

Comment: After filling the request and testing directly I got a "Error reading XMLStreamReader" inside an xml document, AJAX also fails (It returned [object Object], but after changin the error part to simply write '<p>error</p>' on the page, I got that, so ajax failed.


Im not very versed at SOAP but after a quick Google, the problems seems to be that the xml sent was recognized as a SOAP request. Any sugestion on what Im doing wrong at the request?

Comment: Like I said, there is no point in trying the Ajax button until you solve it through the Direct button. Since the Direct button failed, it means that the Ajax is not the problem (which is what I told you at the beginning). The issue is either in the Soap message that you are sending or in the webservice code. We cannot help you without seeing that code, so you can update your question and add the code there and mention which line is throwing the exception.

Comment: I cant currently access the webservice code. After a brief talk we decided to try an api with native codes to make the request as we already have some expertise in java and C# with SOAP. I will keep updating the question with more info as we progress

Thanks for the quick help, as it have us some insight on what to do next and shall I find an answer I'll post it too.

Comment: If you cannot make it work in the standard HTML page above, you will face the same problem in any other language you use. Java will not solve your problem because your problem is not there.